# Problem 5.25 b baby rudin

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, problem-solving, newton-raphson

The exercise goes as follows:

Exercise 5.25:

> **25.** Suppose $f$ is twice differentiable on $[a,b]$, $f(a)\lt 0$, $f(b)\gt 0$, $f'(x)\geq \delta\gt 0$, and $0\leq f''(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Let $\xi$ be the unique point in $(a,b)$ at which $f(\xi) = 0$.
>
> Complete the details in the following outline of *Newton's method* for computing $\xi$.
>
> (a) Choose $x_i\in (\xi,b)$, and define $\{x_n\}$ by
> $$x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}.$$
> Interpret this geometrically, in terms of a tangent to the graph of $f$.
>
> (b) Prove that $x_{n+1}\lt x_n$ and that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x_n = \xi.$$

I have problems regarding part b. I have managed to prove that $x_{n+1}<x_{n}$ and that $\xi<x_{n}<b$ (for all n). I also know that there must be a limit since it is a monotone sequence and it is bounded. However, I do not know how to prove that the desired limit is $\xi$.

I have seen some argument of the sort that if the limit is $\eta$, then we should have that $\eta = \eta - f(\eta)/f'(\eta)$, which would imply $f(\eta)=0$ and so $\eta = \xi$. But I do not understand why is this valid since the limit does not necessarily imply that the sequence $x_{n}$ contains $\eta$.

How could I prove the remaining part of the exercise rigorously?

Comment: $f$ is stricly increasing, hence the uniqueness.

Comment: Please avoid pictures. They are not searchable, they are not accessible, and do not adapt to the person's display.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I take note for the next time. @ArturoMagidin

Answer (score 1):

Consider that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_{n + 1} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n - \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$.

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = 0$. Since $f'(x_n) \geq \delta > 0$ for all $n$, we see that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, this gives us $f(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n) = 0$.

Note that you actually can weaken the hypotheses further. You only need $f$ to be convex and for there to be some $\delta > 0$, $K$ such that $\delta \leq f'(x) \leq K$ for all $x$. Convexity is enough to show that $f(x_n) \geq 0$ for all $x$, while the boundedness of $f'$ is enough to go from $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = 0$ to $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 0$.

Comment: I have one question: is this possible because I have shown that the sequence $x_{n}$ is monotone and it is bounded (so that therefore the limit exists)? In other words, had I not shown it, your reasoning would not have been true, right? By the way, lots of thanks for your answer.

Comment: @epsilondelta Yes, this is only possible because you've shown that the limit exists.